# Delete command for key, Dictionary that contains array of dictionary

Tags: swift, nsmutabledictionary

My Dictionary saves this object

```
class packet: NSObject {
    var time: Double?
    var msgID: Int?
    var hul : String?
    init(time : Double, msgID : Int, hul : String){
        super.init()
        self. time = time
        self.msgID = msgID
        self.hul = hul
    }
}
```

this is my dictionary

```
var ObjectDictionary : NSMutableDictionary = [:]
```

This is Dictionary setValue is like this

```
let obj = packet(time : Date().timeIntervalSince1970, msgID : msgID, hul: hul)
ObjectDictionary.setValue(obj, forKey: String(msgID))
```

Now how can I delete all values from the **ObjectDictionary** where **hul == "SomeString"**

Hope I am clear in explaining the question.

Thanks

Comment: Start by replacing your use of `NSMutableDictionary` with a proper Swift dictionary. But if you choose to use `NSMutableDictionary`, at least avoid the needless use of `setValue(_:forKey:)` and use `setObject(_:forKey:)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a Swift dictionary, not an NSMutableDictionary, and call `filter`:

```
var d = [String:Packet]()
// ... put stuff into the dictionary here ...
let d2 = d.filter{$0.value.hul != "SomeString"}
```

NOTE: I replaced your type name `packet` with Packet. Type names should start with a capital letter in Swift.

Comment: Thanks It worked for me. all I did is d = d.filter{$0.value.hul != "SomeString"}